# Applying the complex Fourier transform to an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

> Solve the following initial value problem :
>   $$y''(t)+y(t)=f(t)=\begin{cases} e^t & \text{if} \ \ t>0 \\1 &
>  \text{if} \ \ t\leq 0 \end{cases}\quad \text{with} \ y(0)=0,t\in
>  \mathbb{R}$$

I took Fourier transform on both sides and got an expression like $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty y''(t)e^{i\omega t}dt+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty y(t)e^{i\omega t}dt=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^0 1.e^{i\omega t}dt+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^t.e^{i\omega t}dt$$$$\implies -\omega^2Y(\omega)+Y(\omega)=\frac{1}{i\omega}+\frac{1}{1+i\omega}\bigg[e^{(1+i\omega)t}\bigg]^\infty_0$$

Now the second integral on the RHS seems to tend to infinity, which is absurd. I sense that I'm doing something wrong as this happens to be a complex integral, so $e^{(1+i\omega)t}$ shouldn't tend to infinity as $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ have their maximum value $1$ over $\mathbb{R}$. What is the possible step that should be taken afterwards in this calculation? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess that $f(t>0)=e^{-t}, f(t<0)=0$, so that last two integrals converge.

Comment: You are changing the whole problem by changing $f(t)$ in that case.

Comment: The right hand side of your ODE doesn't induce a tempered distribution, so it's not something a standard Fourier transform can be applied to. The ODE is linear with constant coefficients, it can easily be solved without Fourier transforms. Is there a specific reason why you want to use a Fourier transform?

Comment: There's no specific reason. I just want to know the fallacy in the above calculation. For example, it is well known that $\mathcal{F}(1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\omega t}dt=\sqrt{2\pi}\delta(\omega)$, but as in my calculation above, it should have been infinity. So mere divergence of the integrals does not imply that Fourier transforms doesn't exist. This thing I just want to verify for the $f(t)$ here.

Comment: That is because this last Fourier transform is only valid in the distributional sense, in any calculus sense this integral does not exist (does not converge, does not have a value). You can extend this distributional argument to growing functions, but the growth does have to be polynomially bounded. Which $e^t$ is not.

Comment: Does the RHS even have a Laplace transform?